# EmbeddedSolrServer in SolrJ 1.4

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using SolrJ 1.4, I am having trouble figuring out in what jar file the EmbeddedSolrServer lives. The documentation says that its namespace is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded but I don't see this namespace among the libraries that make up SolrJ 1.4, according to the [SolrJ Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj).

I am also missing the CoreContainer class that is used to instantiate the EmebbdedSolrServer instance.

Thanks in advance,

Gene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both classes can be found in dist/apache-solr-core-1.4.0.jar of Solr 1.4 package.

Comment: Thanks, I did indeed find that jar in the dist folder of solr. It was just a bit strange that the source code for it was scattered around the source tree.